# Integrate canvas API to a dialogflow chatbot or any chatbot?

Tags: canvas, dialogflow-es, chatbot

I want to make a chatbot in which the user can ask about their grades and assignment.

Basically I want to integrate the canvas API into a chatbot is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Broadly speaking, yes, this is technically possible.

You can create a [fulfillment webhook](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/docs/fulfillment-overview) that gets the Intent and parameters from what the user has said, make the calls to the [Canvas API](https://canvas.instructure.com/doc/api/) based on that information, and return a response to the user.